# Angular js select ng-model binding

Tags: angularjs

i have a big problem with angularjs.
Here is my code:

Controller:

```
function testCt($scope){
    $scope.types = [
        {name:'fruit',label:'To Fruit'},
        {name:'meat',label:'To Meat'},
        {name:'other',label:'To Other'}
    ];

    $scope.foods = [
        {name:'apple',type:'fruit'},
        {name:'raptor',type:'meat'}
    ];

    $scope.selected = null;
    $scope.selectFood = function(food) {
        $scope.selected = food;
    }
};
```

And the view:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="testCt">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="food in foods" ng-click="selectFood(food)">
            {{food.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <select data-ng-model='selected' data-ng-options='t.name as t.label for t in types'></select>
    <br>
    {{selected.name}} <br> {{selected.type}}
</div>
```

The problem is, the angular js not binding to select element the food what i clicked.
Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/p7JJs/

When i choose one food from list, the select element not bind to type.
Thank for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
data-ng-options="t as t.label for t in types"
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WdFuc/)

you have to set `t` as reference, not t.name (no attributes name or type in t.name)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change Your controller function

From

```
   $scope.selectFood = function(food) {
   $scope.selected = food;
   }
```

To

```
   $scope.selectFood = function(food) {
   $scope.selected = food.type;
   }
```

It will work..

Comment: no it wont work :p (no access to selected.name for example ...)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ngSelected? Here're the docs:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected